# MAMP PRO, need MySQL 5.5

Tags: mysql, mamp-pro

How can I use `MySQL 5.5` on latest `Mamp Pro`?

I don't see `MySQL` version switcher on `MySQL` page.
I looked on other tabs/pages but cannot find an answer myself.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Also how can I use "mysql -uroot... < dump" from terminal?

Comment: You cannot run two different versions of MySQL on the same port. You can connect particular MySQL database version by specifying port number e.g, 3306 or 3307 etc.

Comment: The MySQL version can be replaced using the steps in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36000482/1072229). You'll have to change the version numbers to what you want obviously.