# MAMP - MySQL seems to be running but is NOT accepting connections error

Tags: mysql, mamp-pro

I'm using MAMP and I keep getting "MySQL seems to be running but is NOT accepting connections." error.

Also when using `mysql -u root -p` in the terminal, I get the error  `Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)`

I've installed and uninstalled MAMP several times but I still get the same error.

I've appreciate any suggestions.  Below is my *mysql_error.log* info.

```
2021-06-25T16:57:26.6NZ mysqld_safe Logging to '/Applications/MAMP/logs/mysql_error.log'.
2021-06-25T16:57:26.6NZ mysqld_safe Starting mysqld daemon with databases from /Library/Application Support/appsolute/MAMP PRO/db/mysql57
2021-06-25T16:57:26.881140Z 0 [Warning] Insecure configuration for --secure-file-priv: Current value does not restrict location of generated files. Consider setting it to a valid, non-empty path.
2021-06-25T16:57:26.881368Z 0 [Note] /Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/mysqld (mysqld 5.7.32) starting as process 6857 ...
2021-06-25T16:57:26.885086Z 0 [Warning] Setting lower_case_table_names=2 because file system for /Library/Application Support/appsolute/MAMP PRO/db/mysql57/ is case insensitive
2021-06-25T16:57:26.887264Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
2021-06-25T16:57:26.887296Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Uses event mutexes
2021-06-25T16:57:26.887307Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: GCC builtin __atomic_thread_fence() is used for memory barrier
2021-06-25T16:57:26.887319Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.11
2021-06-25T16:57:26.887345Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Adjusting innodb_buffer_pool_instances from 8 to 1 since innodb_buffer_pool_size is less than 1024 MiB
2021-06-25T16:57:26.887620Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Number of pools: 1
2021-06-25T16:57:26.887731Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using CPU crc32 instructions
2021-06-25T16:57:26.888982Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, total size = 128M, instances = 1, chunk size = 128M
2021-06-25T16:57:26.897434Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2021-06-25T16:57:26.911330Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Highest supported file format is Barracuda.
2021-06-25T16:57:26.942003Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Creating shared tablespace for temporary tables
2021-06-25T16:57:26.942205Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Setting file './ibtmp1' size to 12 MB. Physically writing the file full; Please wait ...
2021-06-25T16:57:26.972338Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: File './ibtmp1' size is now 12 MB.
2021-06-25T16:57:26.973320Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: 96 redo rollback segment(s) found. 96 redo rollback segment(s) are active.
2021-06-25T16:57:26.973352Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: 32 non-redo rollback segment(s) are active.
2021-06-25T16:57:26.973662Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
2021-06-25T16:57:27.024380Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: 5.7.32 started; log sequence number 575116050
2021-06-25T16:57:27.024771Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Loading buffer pool(s) from /Library/Application Support/appsolute/MAMP PRO/db/mysql57/ib_buffer_pool
2021-06-25T16:57:27.024875Z 0 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
2021-06-25T16:57:27.027685Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Buffer pool(s) load completed at 210625 12:57:27
2021-06-25T16:57:27.030680Z 0 [Warning] System table 'plugin' is expected to be transactional.
2021-06-25T16:57:27.031574Z 0 [Warning] Gtid table is not ready to be used. Table 'mysql.gtid_executed' cannot be opened.
2021-06-25T16:57:27.035815Z 0 [Note] Found ca.pem, server-cert.pem and server-key.pem in data directory. Trying to enable SSL support using them.
2021-06-25T16:57:27.035844Z 0 [Note] Skipping generation of SSL certificates as certificate files are present in data directory.
2021-06-25T16:57:27.036850Z 0 [Warning] CA certificate ca.pem is self signed.
2021-06-25T16:57:27.036930Z 0 [Note] Skipping generation of RSA key pair as key files are present in data directory.
2021-06-25T16:57:27.038277Z 0 [Warning] Insecure configuration for --pid-file: Location '/Applications/MAMP/tmp' in the path is accessible to all OS users. Consider choosing a different directory.
2021-06-25T16:57:27.038663Z 0 [Warning] Failed to open optimizer cost constant tables

2021-06-25T16:57:27.040913Z 0 [Warning] System table 'time_zone_leap_second' is expected to be transactional.
2021-06-25T16:57:27.040934Z 0 [Warning] System table 'time_zone_name' is expected to be transactional.
2021-06-25T16:57:27.040944Z 0 [Warning] System table 'time_zone' is expected to be transactional.
2021-06-25T16:57:27.040952Z 0 [Warning] System table 'time_zone_transition_type' is expected to be transactional.
2021-06-25T16:57:27.040959Z 0 [Warning] System table 'time_zone_transition' is expected to be transactional.
2021-06-25T16:57:27.041989Z 0 [Warning] System table 'servers' is expected to be transactional.
2021-06-25T16:57:27.043431Z 0 [Warning] Info table is not ready to be used. Table 'mysql.slave_master_info' cannot be opened.
2021-06-25T16:57:27.044068Z 0 [Warning] Info table is not ready to be used. Table 'mysql.slave_relay_log_info' cannot be opened.
2021-06-25T16:57:27.044154Z 0 [Note] Failed to start slave threads for channel ''
2021-06-25T16:57:27.044403Z 0 [ERROR] Incorrect definition of table performance_schema.events_waits_current: expected column 'NESTING_EVENT_TYPE' at position 15 to have type enum('TRANSACTION','STATEMENT','STAGE','WAIT', found type enum('STATEMENT','STAGE','WAIT').
2021-06-25T16:57:27.044531Z 0 [ERROR] Incorrect definition of table performance_schema.events_waits_history: expected column 'NESTING_EVENT_TYPE' at position 15 to have type enum('TRANSACTION','STATEMENT','STAGE','WAIT', found type enum('STATEMENT','STAGE','WAIT').
2021-06-25T16:57:27.044668Z 0 [ERROR] Incorrect definition of table performance_schema.events_waits_history_long: expected column 'NESTING_EVENT_TYPE' at position 15 to have type enum('TRANSACTION','STATEMENT','STAGE','WAIT', found type enum('STATEMENT','STAGE','WAIT').
2021-06-25T16:57:27.045017Z 0 [ERROR] Incorrect definition of table performance_schema.events_waits_summary_by_user_by_event_name: expected column 'USER' at position 0 to have type char(32), found type char(16).
2021-06-25T16:57:27.045142Z 0 [ERROR] Incorrect definition of table performance_schema.events_waits_summary_by_account_by_event_name: expected column 'USER' at position 0 to have type char(32), found type char(16).
2021-06-25T16:57:27.045992Z 0 [ERROR] Column count of performance_schema.setup_actors is wrong. Expected 5, found 3. Created with MySQL 50635, now running 50732. Please use mysql_upgrade to fix this error.
2021-06-25T16:57:27.046268Z 0 [ERROR] Incorrect definition of table performance_schema.setup_objects: expected column 'OBJECT_TYPE' at position 0 to have type enum('EVENT','FUNCTION','PROCEDURE','TABLE','TRIGGER', found type enum('TABLE').
2021-06-25T16:57:27.046748Z 0 [ERROR] Column count of performance_schema.table_lock_waits_summary_by_table is wrong. Expected 68, found 73. Created with MySQL 50635, now running 50732. Please use mysql_upgrade to fix this error.
2021-06-25T16:57:27.046881Z 0 [ERROR] Column count of performance_schema.threads is wrong. Expected 17, found 14. Created with MySQL 50635, now running 50732. Please use mysql_upgrade to fix this error.
2021-06-25T16:57:27.047042Z 0 [ERROR] Column count of performance_schema.events_stages_current is wrong. Expected 12, found 10. Created with MySQL 50635, now running 50732. Please use mysql_upgrade to fix this error.
2021-06-25T16:57:27.047158Z 0 [ERROR] Column count of performance_schema.events_stages_history is wrong. Expected 12, found 10. Created with MySQL 50635, now running 50732. Please use mysql_upgrade to fix this error.
2021-06-25T16:57:27.047282Z 0 [ERROR] Column count of performance_schema.events_stages_history_long is wrong. Expected 12, found 10. Created with MySQL 50635, now running 50732. Please use mysql_upgrade to fix this error.
2021-06-25T16:57:27.047482Z 0 [ERROR] Incorrect definition of table performance_schema.events_stages_summary_by_account_by_event_name: expected column 'USER' at position 0 to have type char(32), found type char(16).
2021-06-25T16:57:27.047605Z 0 [ERROR] Incorrect definition of table performance_schema.events_stages_summary_by_user_by_event_name: expected column 'USER' at position 0 to have type char(32), found type char(16).
2021-06-25T16:57:27.048076Z 0 [ERROR] Column count of performance_schema.events_statements_current is wrong. Expected 41, found 40. Created with MySQL 50635, now running 50732. Please use mysql_upgrade to fix this error.
2021-06-25T16:57:27.048247Z 0 [ERROR] Column count of performance_schema.events_statements_history is wrong. Expected 41, found 40. Created with MySQL 50635, now running 50732. Please use mysql_upgrade to fix this error.
2021-06-25T16:57:27.048402Z 0 [ERROR] Column count of performance_schema.events_statements_history_long is wrong. Expected 41, found 40. Created with MySQL 50635, now running 50732. Please use mysql_upgrade to fix this error.
2021-06-25T16:57:27.048635Z 0 [ERROR] Incorrect definition of table performance_schema.events_statements_summary_by_account_by_event_name: expected column 'USER' at position 0 to have type char(32), found type char(16).
2021-06-25T16:57:27.048760Z 0 [ERROR] Incorrect definition of table performance_schema.events_statements_summary_by_user_by_event_name: expected column 'USER' at position 0 to have type char(32), found type char(16).
2021-06-25T16:57:27.049098Z 0 [ERROR] Native table 'performance_schema'.'events_statements_summary_by_program' has the wrong structure
2021-06-25T16:57:27.049136Z 0 [ERROR] Native table 'performance_schema'.'events_transactions_current' has the wrong structure
2021-06-25T16:57:27.049172Z 0 [ERROR] Native table 'performance_schema'.'events_transactions_history' has the wrong structure
2021-06-25T16:57:27.049208Z 0 [ERROR] Native table 'performance_schema'.'events_transactions_history_long' has the wrong structure
2021-06-25T16:57:27.049238Z 0 [ERROR] Native table 'performance_schema'.'events_transactions_summary_by_thread_by_event_name' has the wrong structure
2021-06-25T16:57:27.049272Z 0 [ERROR] Native table 'performance_schema'.'events_transactions_summary_by_account_by_event_name' has the wrong structure
2021-06-25T16:57:27.049325Z 0 [ERROR] Native table 'performance_schema'.'events_transactions_summary_by_user_by_event_name' has the wrong structure
2021-06-25T16:57:27.049378Z 0 [ERROR] Native table 'performance_schema'.'events_transactions_summary_by_host_by_event_name' has the wrong structure
2021-06-25T16:57:27.049413Z 0 [ERROR] Native table 'performance_schema'.'events_transactions_summary_global_by_event_name' has the wrong structure
2021-06-25T16:57:27.049654Z 0 [ERROR] Incorrect definition of table performance_schema.users: expected column 'USER' at position 0 to have type char(32), found type char(16).
2021-06-25T16:57:27.049817Z 0 [ERROR] Incorrect definition of table performance_schema.accounts: expected column 'USER' at position 0 to have type char(32), found type char(16).
2021-06-25T16:57:27.050456Z 0 [ERROR] Native table 'performance_schema'.'memory_summary_global_by_event_name' has the wrong structure
2021-06-25T16:57:27.050510Z 0 [ERROR] Native table 'performance_schema'.'memory_summary_by_account_by_event_name' has the wrong structure
2021-06-25T16:57:27.050549Z 0 [ERROR] Native table 'performance_schema'.'memory_summary_by_host_by_event_name' has the wrong structure
2021-06-25T16:57:27.050582Z 0 [ERROR] Native table 'performance_schema'.'memory_summary_by_thread_by_event_name' has the wrong structure
2021-06-25T16:57:27.050616Z 0 [ERROR] Native table 'performance_schema'.'memory_summary_by_user_by_event_name' has the wrong structure
2021-06-25T16:57:27.050645Z 0 [ERROR] Native table 'performance_schema'.'table_handles' has the wrong structure
2021-06-25T16:57:27.050674Z 0 [ERROR] Native table 'performance_schema'.'metadata_locks' has the wrong structure
2021-06-25T16:57:27.050706Z 0 [ERROR] Native table 'performance_schema'.'replication_connection_configuration' has the wrong structure
2021-06-25T16:57:27.050735Z 0 [ERROR] Native table 'performance_schema'.'replication_group_members' has the wrong structure
2021-06-25T16:57:27.050767Z 0 [ERROR] Native table 'performance_schema'.'replication_connection_status' has the wrong structure
2021-06-25T16:57:27.050798Z 0 [ERROR] Native table 'performance_schema'.'replication_applier_configuration' has the wrong structure
2021-06-25T16:57:27.050834Z 0 [ERROR] Native table 'performance_schema'.'replication_applier_status' has the wrong structure
2021-06-25T16:57:27.050906Z 0 [ERROR] Native table 'performance_schema'.'replication_applier_status_by_coordinator' has the wrong structure
2021-06-25T16:57:27.050957Z 0 [ERROR] Native table 'performance_schema'.'replication_applier_status_by_worker' has the wrong structure
2021-06-25T16:57:27.050984Z 0 [ERROR] Native table 'performance_schema'.'replication_group_member_stats' has the wrong structure
2021-06-25T16:57:27.051022Z 0 [ERROR] Native table 'performance_schema'.'prepared_statements_instances' has the wrong structure
2021-06-25T16:57:27.051066Z 0 [ERROR] Native table 'performance_schema'.'user_variables_by_thread' has the wrong structure
2021-06-25T16:57:27.051098Z 0 [ERROR] Native table 'performance_schema'.'status_by_account' has the wrong structure
2021-06-25T16:57:27.051150Z 0 [ERROR] Native table 'performance_schema'.'status_by_host' has the wrong structure
2021-06-25T16:57:27.051176Z 0 [ERROR] Native table 'performance_schema'.'status_by_thread' has the wrong structure
2021-06-25T16:57:27.051228Z 0 [ERROR] Native table 'performance_schema'.'status_by_user' has the wrong structure
2021-06-25T16:57:27.051268Z 0 [ERROR] Native table 'performance_schema'.'global_status' has the wrong structure
2021-06-25T16:57:27.051305Z 0 [ERROR] Native table 'performance_schema'.'session_status' has the wrong structure
2021-06-25T16:57:27.051328Z 0 [ERROR] Native table 'performance_schema'.'variables_by_thread' has the wrong structure
2021-06-25T16:57:27.051357Z 0 [ERROR] Native table 'performance_schema'.'global_variables' has the wrong structure
2021-06-25T16:57:27.051411Z 0 [ERROR] Native table 'performance_schema'.'session_variables' has the wrong structure
2021-06-25T16:57:27.051986Z 0 [ERROR] Incorrect definition of table mysql.db: expected column 'User' at position 2 to have type char(32), found type char(16).
2021-06-25T16:57:27.052206Z 0 [ERROR] mysql.user has no `Event_priv` column at position 28
2021-06-25T16:57:27.052562Z 0 [ERROR] Event Scheduler: An error occurred when initializing system tables. Disabling the Event Scheduler.
2021-06-25T16:57:27.052738Z 0 [Note] /Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/mysqld: ready for connections.
Version: '5.7.32'  socket: '/Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql/mysql.sock'  port: 0  MySQL Community Server (GPL)
2021-06-25T16:57:27.154532Z 2 [Note] Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
2021-06-25T16:57:27.171070Z 3 [Note] Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
```

Comment: ithink you should let it run til it shows in the log shows something like Bind-address: '::' port: 33060 it is not finished yet, besides you have some errrors that shoukld be adressed maybe a mysql upgrade

Answer (score 0):

Note: For MySQL 5.7+, please see the answer from [Lahiru][1] to this question. That contains more current information.

For MySQL < 5.7:

The default root password is blank (i.e., an empty string), not root. So you can just log in as:

```
mysql -u root
```

You will also need to upgrade the old DB from mysql56.

```
mysql_upgrade -uroot -p
```

OR try this
MAMP/Library/bin/mysql_upgrade --user=root --password=root --port=3306 --socket=/MAMP/tmp/mysql/mysql.sock --force

[ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21944936/error-1045-28000-access-denied-for-user-rootlocalhost-using-password-y)
[Is it possible to upgrade the MySQL in MAMP to MySQL 5.7?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36000482/is-it-possible-to-upgrade-the-mysql-in-mamp-to-mysql-5-7)
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysql-upgrade.html
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/upgrade-binary-package.html